# How does includeEmptyRows work? - PHP Google Analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I can't retrieve empty rows from GA response. I already set IncludeEmptyRows to true. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code where I initialize request:

```
$dateRange = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate('2016-05-10');
  $dateRange->setEndDate('2016-06-20');

  $sessions = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  $dimension = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
  $dimension->setName("ga:userType");

  $request = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges( $dateRange );
  $request->setMetrics( array($sessions) );
  $request->setDimensions( array($dimension) );
  $request->setIncludeEmptyRows( true );
```

As you see, I set includeEmptyRows to true, but still can't get empty row

```
["data"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["rows"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["dimensions"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(11) "New Visitor"
          }
          ["metrics"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            array(1) {
              ["values"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(2) "63"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

there should be "Returning Visitor" dimension all the time, not only when it is > 0 ( i used different dates here )

```
["data"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["rows"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["dimensions"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(11) "New Visitor"
          }
          ["metrics"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            array(1) {
              ["values"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(3) "159"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["dimensions"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(17) "Returning Visitor"
          }
          ["metrics"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            array(1) {
              ["values"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(1) "5"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Any help? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44394541).

In short, this only works when you're using just a date dimension.  The result for you follow a similar set of steps as the answer linked above, only you would summarize on just the userType dimension after the last step.